# facebook open graph post from private page, but url is public

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a website that needs to be integrated deeply to facebook using open graph. However, I couldn't manage to  publish at least 1 action. I have all my actions approved. So, here comes the problem;

I have a private home page that users see their feed. The home page changes from user to user. However, I have a `website.com/g/user_name/id` page that is public. I'm using php-sdk to publish actions. I have a static singleton facebook helper class that can be reached by this code ;

`Fb::get_instance()->post_timeline( $params);`

The public page ( `website.com/g/user_name/id` ) has all the meta tags correctly. However, I don't have the meta tags in home page because it's all private. So facebook can't parse the meta tags even if I have it in the home page.

What I want is the following ;

When user clicks the add button in home page ( which is private ), the facebook-php-sdk sends a post to publish actions. However, I get the following message ;

`(#3502) Object at URL http://website.com/g/user_name/id has og:type of 'website'. The property '[OBJECT_TYPE]' requires an object of og:type '[APP_NAMESPACE]:[OBJECT_TYPE]'.  (http response code: 206)`

but I'm sure I have `og:type` field in `<head></head>`

IN PUBLIC PAGE ( `http://website.com/g/user_name/id`)

So, what am I doing wrong here ??

Is it possible to make post from private page ??

If not, how can websites like foursquare managed this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Object at URL `http://website.com/g/user_name/id` has **og:type of 'website'**.

That’s what’s wrong …

> The property '[OBJECT_TYPE]' **requires an object of og:type '[APP_NAMESPACE]:[OBJECT_TYPE]'**.

… and this is what it should be.